# Accuracy on NN model decrease after random oversampling using library ROSE

Tags: neural-networks, classification, python, accuracy, oversampling

I did random oversampling to handle unbalanced positive and negative data. When I didn't do random oversampling, the accuracy I got was 88%, when I oversampled the train data, it got 87% accuracy and when I oversampled the train data and tests, the accuracy was 84%. Here's the oversampling code:

```
from collections import Counter
from imblearn.over_sampling import RandomOverSampler

ros = RandomOverSampler(random_state=0)
Train_X2_rose, Train_Y2_rose = ros.fit_resample(Train_X2_Tfidf, Train_Y2)
Test_X2_rose, Test_Y2_rose = ros.fit_resample(Test_X2_Tfidf, Test_Y2)

#classification model trial 10
def reset_seeds():
   np.random.seed(0) 
   python_random.seed(0)
   tf.random.set_seed(0)

reset_seeds() 

model10 = Sequential()
model10.add(Dense(10, input_dim= Train_X2_rose.shape[1], activation='sigmoid'))
model10.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
opt = Adam (learning_rate=0.01)
model10.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
model10.summary()

es = EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss",mode='min',patience=10)
history10 = model10.fit(Train_X2_rose, Train_Y2_rose, epochs=1000, verbose=1, 
                        validation_split=0.2, batch_size=64, callbacks =[es])

#prediction and confusion matrix
y_pred = model10.predict(Test_X2_rose) > 0.5

print(confusion_matrix(Test_Y2_rose, y_pred))
print(classification_report(Test_Y2_rose, y_pred))
print('Confusion matrix:')
confusion_matrix(Test_Y2_rose, y_pred)
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,5))
sns.heatmap(confusion_matrix(Test_Y2_rose, y_pred), annot=True, fmt=".0f", ax=ax)
plt.xlabel("y_head")
plt.ylabel("y_true")
plt.show()

cm = confusion_matrix(Test_Y2_rose, y_pred)
```

Why does this decrease in accuracy occur? is there something wrong with my code? because I used hyperparameter tuning with 18 models and some models with oversampling showed a very strange plot loss and accuracy where the training and validation data lines split above and below.

Comment: Accuracy is a highly problematic KPI, even (but not only) in the "unbalanced" case: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352. "Imbalance" is usually not a problem, and oversampling is usually not a solution: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/357466/1352

Comment: Why are you oversampling the test data? The purpose of oversampling is to ensure that the positives and negatives across the training data are balanced so the model can make more accurate predictions. The test data should not be touched - the entire purpose of comparing prediction results to test data is to see how the model would perform on completely unseen data - which may well also be unbalanced in a real-world situation.